# Python: Speed up FOR loops while searching through csv files

Tags: python, csv

I have several distributors that supply me with CSV files of their inventory levels.  Some of these distributors have as many as 3 files with info. These files are pretty large, with 170,000+ rows of data.

What I'm trying to do is write a program that allows me to reorganize this data into a new CSV file so every distributor would have one file organized the way I wish.

Here's a little run down on what I'm doing with the code without going too technical:

```
step 1
Open file1
  for row1 in file1  
    Grab partnumber from row[1]

    step 2    
    open file2
      for row2 in file2
        if partnumber == row2[2]
          grab data from row[4]
          break
```

Step 2 is then repeated for every piece of data I want to pull.  The problem I'm seeing is the program runs very quickly until it gets further into the data, since it still reads every line of data even if I've already collected from the line of text.  I've even thought well what if I start deleting the line of data when I'm finished with it but I thought maybe there was an alternative I don't know about.  Any help would be great.

```
def PartSearch():
    Partexists = "N"
    global SelectedObject
    with open(eval("file"+str(SelectedFile))) as f:        
        r2 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = eval("file"+str(SelectedFile)+"Del"))
        for row2 in r2:                 
            if int(SelectedFile) == 1:                                
                if str(row2[int(file1PartNumber)]) == str(PartNumberobject):                    
                    Partexists= "Y"
                    SelectedObject =  row2[int(SelectedCol)]
                    break
            if int(SelectedFile) == 2:
                if row2[int(file2PartNumber)] == PartNumberobject:
                    Partexists= "Y"
                    SelectedObject =  row2[int(SelectedCol)]
                    break
            if int(SelectedFile) == 3:
                if row2[int(file3PartNumber)] == PartNumberobject:
                    Partexists= "Y"
                    SelectedObject =  row2[int(SelectedCol)]
                    break
            if int(SelectedFile) == 4: 
                if row2[int(file4PartNumber)] == PartNumberobject:
                    Partexists= "Y"
                    SelectedObject =  row2[int(SelectedCol)]  
                    break        
        if Partexists != "Y":
            SelectedObject = "X" 


with open("C:\\Python34\\Python34\\Distributors\\ListOfDistributors.txt") as f:        
        r3 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
        for row3 in r3:
            distributor = row3[0]
            with open("C:\\Python34\\Python34\\Distributors\\"+distributor+"files.txt") as f:        
                r4 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
                totalRows = sum(1 for _ in f)
                i = totalRows


                if totalRows == 1:
                    with open("C:\\Python34\\Python34\\Distributors\\"+distributor+"files.txt") as f:        
                        r4 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
                        for row4 in r4:
                            file1 = row4[1]
                            file1Del = row4[2]
                            file1titles = row4[3]
                            file1titles = row4[3]
                            file1PartNumber = row4[4]


                if totalRows == 2:
                    with open("C:\\Python34\\Python34\\Distributors\\"+distributor+"files.txt") as f:        
                        r4 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
                        for row4 in r4:
                            if i == 2:
                                file1 = row4[1]
                                file1Del = row4[2]
                                file1titles = row4[3]
                                file1titles = row4[3]
                                file1PartNumber = row4[4]


                            if i == 1:
                                file2 = row4[1]
                                file2Del = row4[2]
                                file2titles = row4[3]
                                file2titles = row4[3]
                                file2PartNumber = row4[4]
                            i = i-1


                if totalRows == 3:
                    with open("C:\\Python34\\Python34\\Distributors\\"+distributor+"files.txt") as f:        
                        r4 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
                        for row4 in r4:
                            if i == 3:
                                file1 = row4[1]
                                file1Del = row4[2]
                                file1titles = row4[3]
                                file1titles = row4[3]
                                file1PartNumber = row4[4]

                            if i == 2:                        
                                file2 = row4[1]
                                file2Del = row4[2]
                                file2titles = row4[3]
                                file2titles = row4[3]
                                file2PartNumber = row4[4]

                            if i == 1:                                
                                file3 = row4[1]
                                file3Del = row4[2]
                                file3titles = row4[3]
                                file3titles = row4[3]
                                file3PartNumber = row4[4]
                            i = i-1


                if totalRows == 4:
                    with open("C:\\Python34\\Python34\\Distributors\\"+distributor+"files.txt") as f:        
                        r4 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
                        for row4 in r4:
                            if i == 4:
                                file1 = row4[1]
                                file1Del = row4[2]
                                file1titles = row4[3]
                                file1titles = row4[3]
                                file1PartNumber = row4[4]

                            if i == 3:                        
                                file2 = row4[1]
                                file2Del = row4[2]
                                file2titles = row4[3]
                                file2titles = row4[3]
                                file2PartNumber = row4[4]

                            if i == 2:                                
                                file3 = row4[1]
                                file3Del = row4[2]
                                file3titles = row4[3]
                                file3titles = row4[3]
                                file3PartNumber = row4[4]
                            if i == 1:
                                file4 = row4[1]
                                file4Del = row4[2]
                                file4titles = row4[3]
                                file4titles = row4[3]
                                file4PartNumber = row4[4]

                            i = i-1




            with open("C:\\Python34\\Python34\\Distributors\\"+distributor+"structure.txt") as f:
                  r5 = csv.reader(f, delimiter = "\t")
                  i=1
                  for row5 in r5:
                      if i == 1:
                            DistributorName = row5[0]



                            PartNumberFile =  row5[2] 
                            PartNumberCol =  row5[3]


                            AltPartNumberFile =  row5[5] 
                            AltPartNumberCol =  row5[6]


                            VendorPartNumberFile =  row5[8] 
                            VendorPartNumberCol =  row5[9]

                            AltVendorPartNumberFile =  row5[11] 
                            AltVendorPartNumberCol =  row5[12]

                            DescriptionFile =  row5[14] 
                            DescriptionCol =  row5[15]

                            BrandFile =  row5[17] 
                            BrandCol =  row5[18]

                            CostFile =  row5[20] 
                            CostCol =  row5[21]

                            RetailFile =  row5[23] 
                            RetailCol =  row5[24]

                            StatusFile =  row5[26] 
                            StatusCol =  row5[27]

                            WeightFile =  row5[29] 
                            WeightCol =  row5[30]



                      if i == 2:
                            if row5[2] == 0:
                                NumofOnedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                            if row5[2] == 1:
                                NumofOnedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Oneday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Oneday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                            if row5[2] == 2:
                                NumofOnedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Oneday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Oneday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Oneday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Oneday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                            if row5[2] == 3:
                                NumofOnedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Oneday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Oneday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Oneday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Oneday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                                Oneday3WarehouseFile = row5[10]
                                Oneday3WarehouseCol = row5[11]


                      if i == 3:
                            if row5[2] == 0:
                                NumofTwodaywarehouse = row5[2]
                            if row5[2] == 1:
                                NumofTwodaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Twoday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Twoday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                            if row5[2] == 2:
                                NumofTwodaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Twoday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Twoday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Twoday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Twoday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                            if row5[2] == 3:
                                NumofTwodaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Twoday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Twoday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Twoday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Twoday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                                Twoday3WarehouseFile = row5[10]
                                Twoday3WarehouseCol = row5[11]


                      if i == 4:
                            if row5[2] == 0:
                                NumofThreedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                            if row5[2] == 1:
                                NumofThreedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Threeday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Threeday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                            if row5[2] == 2:
                                NumofThreedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Threeday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Threeday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Threeday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Threeday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                            if row5[2] == 3:
                                NumofThreedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Threeday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Threeday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Threeday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Threeday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                                Threeday3WarehouseFile = row5[10]
                                Threeday3WarehouseCol = row5[11]


                      if i == 5:
                            if row5[2] == 0:
                                NumofFourdaywarehouse = row5[2]
                            if row5[2] == 1:
                                NumofFourdaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Fourday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Threeday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                            if row5[2] == 2:
                                NumofFourdaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Fourday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Fourday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Fourday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Fourday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                            if row5[2] == 3:
                                NumofFourdaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Fourday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Fourday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Fourday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Fourday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                                Fourday3WarehouseFile = row5[10]
                                Fourday3WarehouseCol = row5[11]


                      if i == 6:
                            if row5[2] == 0:
                                NumofFivedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                            if row5[2] == 1:
                                NumofFivedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Fiveday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Fiveday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                            if row5[2] == 2:
                                NumofFivedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Fiveday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Fiveday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Fiveday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Fiveday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                            if row5[2] == 3:
                                NumofFivedaywarehouse = row5[2]
                                Fiveday1WarehouseFile = row5[4]
                                Fiveday1WarehouseCol = row5[5]
                                Fiveday2WarehouseFile = row5[7]
                                Fiveday2WarehouseCol = row5[8]
                                Fiveday3WarehouseFile = row5[10]
                                Fiveday3WarehouseCol = row5[11]
                      i = i+1




            """print(file1Del)   
            PartNumberFile = 1
            PartNumberCol = 1

            CostFile = 2
            CostCol = 2

            SelectedFile = PartNumberFile
            SelectedCol = PartNumberCol

            number = 1"""


            #Program to grab Part Number
            with open(file1) as f:

                    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter = file1Del)
                    if file1titles == "Y":
                          file=r.__next__()  
                    for row in r:                        
                        PartNumberobject = row[int(file1PartNumber)]

                        "start of data collection, save variables as SelectedFile and SelectedCol. Run PartSearch() then save Variable SelectedObject"

                        SelectedFile = PartNumberFile
                        SelectedCol = PartNumberCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FPartNumber = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = AltPartNumberFile
                        SelectedCol = AltPartNumberCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FAltPartNumber = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = VendorPartNumberFile
                        SelectedCol = VendorPartNumberCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FVendorPartNumber = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = AltVendorPartNumberFile
                        SelectedCol = AltVendorPartNumberCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FAltVendorPartNumber = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = DescriptionFile
                        SelectedCol = DescriptionCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FDescription = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = BrandFile
                        SelectedCol = BrandCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FBrand = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = CostFile
                        SelectedCol = CostCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FCost = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = RetailFile
                        SelectedCol = RetailCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FRetail = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = StatusFile
                        SelectedCol = StatusCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FStatus = SelectedObject


                        SelectedFile = WeightFile
                        SelectedCol = WeightCol

                        PartSearch()

                        FWeight = SelectedObject


                        print(DistributorName, PartNumberobject, FAltPartNumber, FVendorPartNumber, FAltVendorPartNumber, FDescription, FBrand, FCost, FRetail, FStatus, FWeight)
```

Comment: can you show us your code? We can't help with what we can't see

Comment: Please include the actual code. Avoiding being "too technical" is not a good goal on this site.

Comment: You have 3 files with ~170000 rows. Assuming each row has ~80 length then this is around ~40Mb of data (even if it were 10x more it still is nothing). Thus I suggest you load all of that into memory prior to to processing. Next (and more important) optimization would be to create an index on `file2`, i.e. convert `file2` after loading into a dictionary/set so you can test `if partnumber in file2` in `O(1)` time. If you need to copy `file2` then do it, 400Mb of additional memory is still nothing nowadays. That should be more then enough.

Comment: You can open multiple files at once: `with open('file1', 'r') as f1, open('file2', 'r') as f2, open('file3', 'r') as f3, open('newfile', 'w') as newfile:` and nest the rest of your code inside.

Comment: I apologize but my religion does not allow me to read code longer then 100 lines. You really need to split it into functions.

Comment: I added my code to the question.  Most of it is just pulling info from a look up sheet so it knows where the data is located in what column of each csv.

Comment: My biggest concern is PartSearch(), PartSearch() is where I start rifling through the tables and collecting data.

Comment: Definitely a good use case for `pandas`. Specifically look at `join`ing 2 dataframes on "part number". I doubt that you can get much faster than that in pure python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your the part file is small enough to fit in memory, you can speed this up by loading it into a dictionary (efficient, fast access data structure). When you loop through `file2`, you're looking for a line where `row[2] == partnumber`, and then (presumably) taking using `row[4]`, so a dictionary with `row[2]` as the key and `row[4]` as the value would make the lookup really fast:

```
parts = {}
with [however you open CSV 2] as f:
    for row in f:
        parts[row[2]] = row[4]
```

Then instead of re-opening that file every time, just do:

```
data = parts[partnumber]
```

---

EDIT: There are also a bunch of other things you can do to make this code better:

- Consider following [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), since it will make it easier for other people to read your code. Having a bunch of variables starting with upper-case letters is tricking the syntax highlighting on this site into thinking they're classes.
- Use `True` and `False` for booleans, rather than the strings "Y" and "N".

  ```
  part_exists = False
  if some_condition:
      part_exists = True
  if part_exists:
      selected_object = "X" # not clear what this does so I'm not messing with it
  ```
- When you're splitting an array into variables, you can do that much more easily:

  ```
  for row4 in r4:
      file1, file1Del, file1titles, file1PartNumber = row
  ```
- You repeat a lot of code to handle the case of one row, two rows, three rows, and four rows. Consider using loops and lists here. It would also let you get rid of that `eval`.

This may seem like pointless nitpicking, but code that doesn't repeat so much is *much* easier to improve.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really provide details, I can answer only very general.

Given that you want to work with few csv files only, and given that their size is approximately 170k lines, I assume that these data fit in the memory. if this is the case, and you want to work in python (a very reasonable choice), I would highly recommend that you invest some time to learn pandas. Pandas gives you a vast amount of options to work with tabular data, including powerful filtering or database-style merge and join operations.

When you then ask a more specific question, I am sure that we can provide further help.